# Flash video not stopping in jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-plugins

I have a slider which has 2 slides, on each slide I loaded flash videos.

I played the flash video and moved to next slide.

In FF and Chrome the first flash video is stopped, when i click the next slide. But in IE the video is not stopping.

Any suggestions?

JS Fiddle url for HTML structure: http://jsfiddle.net/cHbu5/

Below is the js.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$('#slides').slides({          
    generatePagination: true,
    hoverPause: true,
    // Get the starting slide
    start: 1           
});
```

Comment: Edited the question now: http://jsfiddle.net/cHbu5/